# How to retrieve SQL error code on postgres database via DataAccessException?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to delete a record from database using spring data jpa on postgresql database  and I need to capture the sql error code

```
try {
    userRepository.deleteUser(id);
} catch(org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException e) {
    // here
}
```

How do I get the sql error code in catch block? getCause or getMessage method is not retrieving sql error code

Comment: What about `getRootCause()`? That should return the original JDBC exception

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working with getRootCause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [official JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/SQLExceptionTranslator.html) of the interface `SQLExceptionTranslator` we find this hint:

> The returned DataAccessException is *supposed* to contain the *original* `SQLException` as root cause. However, client code may not generally rely on this due to DataAccessExceptions possibly *being caused by other resource APIs* as well. That said, a `getRootCause() instanceof SQLException` check (and subsequent cast) is considered **reliable** when expecting JDBC-based access to have happened.

So, with this information in mind, you can write code like this:

```
try {
    userRepository.deleteUser(id);

} catch(org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException e) {
    if( e.getRootCause() instanceof SQLException) {
        SQLException sqlEx = (SQLException) e.getRootCause();
        int sqlErrorCode = sqlEx.getErrorCode();
        // do further things from here on...
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working fine with the above code